# Automate su login without password prompt

Tags: sudo, su

I am writing a shell script where I want to automate service Restart process on multiple Unix servers. I as a normal user do not have rights to run services restart commands. Only **s_user** has rights to run them.

Procedure to restart services:

1. **Login to server with my username and password.**
2. **To Run the Restart service I need to switch user to s_user using below command:** ( I need this command without password prompt)

   ```
   sudo su - s_user
   ```

The above command prompts for password where I will provide my password to restart services. This procedure I have to do in all the servers.**I want to skip the password prompt by supplying the password to su through stdin.**

The following commands I have tried so far:

```
1.   echo 'password'|sudo -S su -c " .../bin/services stop" 
Output:
[sudo]password for abc.xyz: Sorry, user abc.xyz is not allowed to execute '/bin/su - s_user' -c /bin/services stop' as root on [Servername]
```

In the above command I gave my password. I have also tried giving the s_user password but it gives below output:

```
[sudo]password for abc.xyz: Sorry,try again.
[sudo]password for abc.xyz:
sudo:pam_authenticate:Conversation error
```

I replaced ‘su’ with ‘u’ in the below command, but still I am getting the same output error as 1st command.

```
2.  echo 'password'|sudo -S u -c " .../bin/services stop"
```

I have provided s_user in the below command, but still I am getting the same output error as 1st command.

```
3.  echo 'password'|sudo -S su - s_user -c ".../bin/service stop"
```

Next I have tried the below command.

```
4.  echo 'my password'|su -c ".../bin/services stop" -s /bin/sh abc.xyz
Output:
Standard in must be a tty
```

I have also tried the below command.

```
5.  su -c "command_to_restart_the_services" -s /bin/sh abc.xyz
```

I am able to run the command successfully.

```
6.  echo password|sudo -S su - user-to-switch
    sudo -S su - user-to-switch
```

The above command still ask for the password.

Restrictions:

•   I cannot use **“expect”**, it’s not installed in my machines.

•   I cannot edit the **"sudoer"** file. I do not have rights.

Comment: I would convince the sysadmin to configure sudo to allow me to restart the services directly, with or without a password prompt as desired.

Comment: single sign-on feature

Comment: You don't need to use `su` with `sudo`. `sudo` has an option to specify a sure `-u`. And your admin gave you full root access, using sudo. Add the sudo configuration yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I see you are using `sudo` to become root, and then `su` to become `s_user`. To do this you will use your password (for `sudo`). You do not need the password for `s_user`.

You could do it by instead adding your ssh key to the `s_user` account, but I think this solution in this case is sub-optimal.

First I will point out that you don't need `su`, and it is best not to use it. So instead of `sudo su - s_user -c command`, do `sudo -u s_user command`. You will still be asked for your password. However you can now configure `/etc/sudoers`

Add a file `/etc/sudoers.d/s_commands`, containing something like (but checked, with `/usr/bin/visudo`):

```
Cmnd_Alias S_COMMAND=/usr/bin/command, /usr/bin/anotherCommand
%s_group ALL = (s_user) NOPASSWD : S_COMMAND
```

This will allow password less use of those commands, as s_user, but only for users in group s_group (you will have to add the group).

Then set up a shell alias, something like: `alias s_command="sudo -u s_user command"`.

---

Notes:

- `su` takes the password of the user that you are switching to.
- `sudo`, by default, takes the password of the user you are (you are switching from).
- `sudo` does not read password from stdin, it reads from tty.

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this is to use ssh.

Using ssh-copy-id you can store the authentification:

```
ssh-copy-id s_user@127.0.0.1
```

(if no key have been set, use `ssh-keygen` to generate one)

Next you can use `ssh` instead of sudo to execute command without password prompt:

```
ssh s_user@127.0.0.1 " .../bin/services stop"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am new to this unix environment. Can you please provide some more details on when to run this command i mean after doing sudo login? Also, I am not sure what would be the impact post implementing these. These servers are currently in use and I am afraid if something goes wrong.Can you please provide me step by step guide to perform this authenfication task. Please help!!!

Comment: Somehow the `ssh s_user@127.0.0.1` command makes something equivalent to `sudo -u s_user`, after running  `ssh-copy-id s_user@127.0.0.1` that prompt for password the ssh command doesnot prompt for password.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly the answer to your question, but could be a solution for your task.

I suppose you know the password for s_user on every server, and there is `sshd` installed on those servers (and works as expected; depends on what OS runs on the servers).

As [mpromonet](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/56338/mpromonet) stated, you may use ssh, but without logging into the servers with your own credentials.

On your computer:

First, generate your own key pair with `ssh-keygen`. This will be stored in ~/.ssh directory by default.

Next, for every server involved call `ssh-copy s_user@<server>`; you will be asked for the password of s_user on the server.

Now to check if all went well just try `ssh s_user@<server>`. If this works without being asked for a password your done.

In your script (on your local computer) you now can call

`ssh s_user@<server> "whatever-command-you-need-to-run"`

without beeing asked for passwords.

Rem.: I supposed here your local computer runs a UN*X like OS as well. If you are running Windows, you may instead use the programs coming with the `putty` packet for Windows.