# Why can sudo read a stdin password, but su not?

Tags: bash, shell-script

This means in a script one can do this:

```
echo "rootpassword" | sudo -S -k su notheruser
```

But not this:

```
echo "notheruserpassword" | su notheruser
```

The first is inherently less secure than the second.

Is there anyway to pass a user's password in via stdin and have the script su to that user?

Comment: See [this answer on Super User](https://superuser.com/a/1343270/432690).

Comment: Are you sure you’re using the root password in the first variant? Are you aware of the `-u` option with `sudo`?

Comment: See also [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/304704/86440) (I don’t want to close this directly, I have a hammer here).

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski  I don't think expect is installed by default on many versions of linux.  So not really a default solution.

Comment: @Stephen Kit: -u sets the user for the command, but does not impact the requirement for the root password to be supplied.

Comment: @Stephen Kit: thanks for that link - it seems silly that one can switch to root in a shell script, but not to an ordinary user without first becoming root.  There should be an idiomatic way for shell scripts to switch to other users based a password.  Whilst the question is legit, I think there is no good answer, so I'll understand if you close.

Comment: `sudo -u` doesn’t need the root password, it needs the password of the current user. If the current user is root, it shouldn’t be necessary to provide a password at all. You can also configure `sudo` to ask for the target password.

Comment: Passwords should be secret and personal: embedding them into scripts is a bad idea. `sudo` is configurable to let specific users run specific (or unlimited) commands as specific (or any) other users, *and to optionally waive the requirement to enter a password while doing so*. Sudo requiring the password of the destination user instead of the user running the sudo command is a relatively unusual configuration that used to be the default of SuSE Linux; but that default can be changed . See the `rootpw`, `targetpw` and `runaspw` flags in `man sudoers`.

Comment: @Stephen Kitt - you are right - it requires the sudoer's password - but not the user being su to's password

Comment: @telcoM: thank you for the info.  targetpw looks like the right behaviour, but it should only apply to some scripts, not the machine - any ideas on how this can be achieved?

Comment: See the various types of `Defaults` entries in `man sudoers`. In a modern version of sudo, you can apply changes to `sudo`'s default settings globally, per hostname (if using a shared sudoers file), per originating user, per destination user, or even per command to execute. One of those should work for you... but you should also consider configuring sudo to allow a specific originating user to run the needed command(s) as the specific target user through sudo *without having to enter a password at all*. That would simplify your scripting and remove the requirement to embed passwords in script.

Comment: Consider: if `sudo` is configured to only allow specific commands without a password requirement, an unauthorized person gaining access to the first user account will only be able to do what the script could do in the first place. If an embedded password is used, the unauthorized person would be able to read the password from the script, use `su` to switch to the target account and do whatever they please.

Comment: @telcoM - thanks for the info I'll explore.  No password is being embedded, the user is being prompted for their password and that is piped to stdin (not echo'ed as shown).